# Unable to install OpenCV Python on M1 Mac

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I've been following this thread (https://trayansh.medium.com/setting-machine-learning-environment-on-m1-mac-apple-silicon-959836bf494d), successfully installed TensorFlow but while making the config file(Cmake Command) for openCV it is giving me an error:-

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:354 (message):
  Duplicated modules LOCATIONS has been found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:371 (_assert_uniqueness)
  modules/CMakeLists.txt:7 (ocv_glob_modules)
```

I've been trying to install it for two days now and no progress. :(

The CMake command I used was

```
cmake \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm64 \
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=arm64 \
-DWITH_OPENJPEG=OFF \
-DWITH_IPP=OFF \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/yashdhingra/Documents/Python/opencompile/opencv-4.5.0/modules \
-D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/MLenv/python3 \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

I did change the path of the modules and the Virtual Env_python as instructed in the guide.

Comment: Please, add to the question post the **exact** `cmake` command which you run for OpenCV.  The link you refers to suggests many parameters to this command, so it could be that some of them are wrong.

Comment: Have a look. I've added the command I used.

Answer (score 0):

This CMake error (Duplicated modules LOCATIONS has been found) is because you point the extra modules path to the main opencv module you are trying to build from.
You need to set the extra modules path to opencv-contrib and not opencv.

> OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/Users/yashdhingra/Documents/Python/opencompile/**opencv_contrib-4.5.0**/modules

Answer (score 0):

You have perhaps copied the extra modules into the main module directory, and then are using -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/OpenCV3.4/modules to locate this.  But the module locator looks at ALL the modules that are in a directory; and then it also requires each module to be unique and seen only once.  Since the cmake looks at all the modules in the main /module directory by default, and then looks at all the modules in the EXTRA_MODULES path **again** when you specify this cmake option, it gets confused, and thinks it is seeing the exact same modules twice, and then barfs.

Solution 1:  Simply don't specify -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/opt/OpenCV3.4/modules in your cmake instructions *if* you have included all extra modules into the default system module file by hand.  It will only review this directory once, and will happily compile all of them.

Solution 2:  Keep the extra modules in their own separate directory, and specify cmake option -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/my_extra_modules_directory which is separate from the main /modules directory.

Comment: Note that you have to wipe out all the files under your /build directory after you make this fix, as cmake is sticky from previous invocations.